# Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

After upgrading firebase_auth from earlier version to ^0.8.0+1 generates error for me. 
Here is error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Changelog, you have to perform a migration in the Android project to AndroidX.

The details of the [changes required are here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

See CHANGELOG:

> 0.8.0
>   Breaking change. Migrate from the deprecated original Android Support Library to AndroidX. This shouldn't result in any functional changes, but it requires any Android apps using this plugin to [also migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) if they're using the original support library.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly set the **compileSdkVersion** to **28** in the android/app/build.gradle file.
Secondly add the following to your android/gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```